# Can I use a creature's ability on my opponent's turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I were to have a card on the battlefield such as [Archers' Parapet](http://magiccards.info/query?q=archers%27%20parapet&v=card&s=cname) and it was my opponents turn could I play the ability of Parapet if I had player priority?

> {1}{B}, {T}: Each opponent loses 1 life.

I am wondering if it is possible to play the ability during my opponents end step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a tap ability at instant speed, so as long as the cost is payed and the creature does NOT have summoning sickness you may use the ability whenever you have priority.

Comment: It might be worth noting cards that say, "use this ability only anytime you could cast a Sorcery" would be excluded.